# Infinea Tab iOS PhoneGap Integration

Tags: ios, sdk, cordova

Here is my issue. We have developed a POS system for our event team to run transactions while mobile. The app was a webapp but now it is native app via phonegap. We have purchased the Infinea Tab 2 (http://ipcprint.com/ios-peripherals/infinea-tab2.html) and are now trying to integrate the credit card swiper into the now native app. I obviously need access to the sdk to get the data from the swiper and then need to feed it into the phonegap app. I have heard this is possible via a phonegap plugin (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html) but I am unsure. So my question is there any way to gain access to c++ sdk's data within a phonegap app? Any help would be appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ys, it's possible with a plugin, read the guide you linked

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that was a legitimate route. Would you happen to have any links to other tutorials out there. Sorry I am very new to all this app development so my head is just spinning right now.

Comment: I know a tutorial but it's in spanish. You can take a look to existing plugins https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins